# Django - models.ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

Thanks for checking this out.

Silly doubt of mine:

I have the following models defined in Django:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField() # positive integer only accepts positives
    school = models.ForeignKey("School", related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My question is: How does Django knows to pick the School.name field as a match for the foreign key school?
As when I check on the Admin page and add a student, I can select the name of the school (as the foreign key).
Name:
Age:
School = (drop down with the name of the schools)

Is it the order of the elements or something else?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It does not, it uses the primary key by default. It *renders* the school with `self.name` because that is what **`__str__` returns**.

So for example if you make a `ModelChoiceField`, then it will render HTML that looks like:

```
<select name="school">
    <option value="1">Name of School 1</option>
    <option value="2">Name of School 2</option>
    <option value="3">Name of School 3</option>
</select>
```

So when you submit the form, Django retrieves the primary key. The `Name of School 1`, is obtained because it calls [**`str(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) on the model objects. This will in its turn, if you specified it, call `__str__`, and the result of `__str__` will be used to *render* the school. But for example in URLs, forms, etc. the primary key is used to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: Awesome! This makes much more sense now! Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and example. Cheers!!!! :)